# Invariant Violation when using Drawer from react-navigation-drawer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting an invariant violation when trying to use the Drawer from react-navigation-drawer in my code.

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `ProfileScreen`.

Here's the return of the screen that is causing the issue to trigger:

```js
      <View>
        <Drawer ref={(ref) => {this.drawer = ref}}
        type="static"
        tapToClose={true}
        openDrawerOffset={0.35}
        content={this.renderDrawer}
        style={drawerStyles}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{alignItems: "flex-end", margin: 16}}
          onPress={() => this.openDrawer.bind(this)}>
          <FontAwesome5 name="bars" size={24} color="161924"/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
              <View style={{marginTop: 30, alignItems: "center"}}>
                  <View style={styles.avatarContainer}>
                      <Image style={styles.avatar}
                      source={require('../../../assets/logo.png')}/>
                  </View>
                  <Text style={styles.name}> Juan Gómez </Text>
              </View>   
              <View style={styles.statsContainer}>
                  <View style={styles.stat}> 
                    <Text style={styles.statAmount}> 21 </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.statTitle}> Entregas en curso </Text> 
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.stat}> 
                    <Text style={styles.statAmount}> 88 </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.statTitle}> Donaciones en curso </Text> 
                  </View>
              </View>
              <SwitchSelector 
              buttonColor="#013773"
              fontSize={16}
              hasPadding
              style={{ transform: [{ scaleX: .95 }, { scaleY: .95 }] }}
              options={options} 
              initial={0} 
              onPress={value => console.log(`Call onPress with value: ${value}`)} />
        </ScrollView>
        </Drawer>
      </View>
```

And stack trace:

```
This error is located at:
    in RCTView (at Profile/index.js:64)
    in ProfileScreen (at SceneView.tsx:98)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:89)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:88)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:125)
    in RCTView (at BottomTabView.tsx:38)
    in SceneContent (at BottomTabView.tsx:122)
    in RCTView (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:44)
    in RCTView (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:27)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at BottomTabView.tsx:117)
    in RCTView (at screens.native.js:131)
    in ScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:101)
    in RCTView (at BottomTabView.tsx:100)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:99)
    in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:41)
    in BottomTabNavigator (at Home/index.js:17)
    in Home (at SceneView.tsx:98)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:89)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:88)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:125)
    in RCTView (at CardContainer.tsx:190)
    in RCTView (at CardContainer.tsx:189)
    in RCTView (at Card.tsx:520)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Card.tsx:503)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:496)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Card.tsx:492)
    in RCTView (at Card.tsx:486)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:156)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:531)
    in RCTView (at CardStack.tsx:106)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:524)
    in RCTView (at CardStack.tsx:89)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:422)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:384)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:382)
    in RNCSafeAreaView (at src/index.tsx:26)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:379)
    in RCTView (at StackView.tsx:378)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:67)
    in StackNavigator (at App.js:17)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:268)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:39)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:38)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:16)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:26)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:25)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

renderRoot
    [native code]:0
runRootCallback
    [native code]:0
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    [native code]:0
```

I assume there's something I made wrong when placing the Drawer tags but I don't know what else to try.

Comment: I've put the stack trace and error in your post because [that's where they should have been in the first place](/help/how-to-ask). Don't link out to problem-relevant data, put it in your post. With that said: the error is talking about the `render()` method in ProfileScreen, so what does that code look like? Similarly, the rest of the error also contains things that you need to double check: did you? (the code you're showing seems unrelated to your problem, why did you decide it was this code you should be showing? Because that reasoning should probably also go into your post)

Comment: There is something wrong in `ProfileScreen` component.  Please add it.

Comment: Can you post the entire code and the links such as imports and also the files from where the imports are fetched ?

Comment: The issue is probably in the `{this.renderDrawer}` line can you please post this function?

Comment: can you add the imports you have as well?